# Need for a demo: movies database

Tags: database

For a internal demonstration of powerPivot/silverlight 5/asp.net MVC 3/... I need to find a database with a large set of data, including images.

I'm searching a database with a lot of movies, including their cover.

I saw that IMDB gives an access to its file, but not images.

Do you know an open enough provider for this kind of data?

Thank you!

Comment: This topic is not programming related.

Comment: but this really can help programmers

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid: Agreed.  I'd thought about voting to close as well, but all too often in my career I've found myself looking for useful APIs on the internet.  Maybe at best this can be migrated to Programmers SE, but I hate to use that site as a dumping ground for all borderline off-topic questions.

Comment: @David the thing is, we go to any forum or any other field of the world for that matter, we are likely to find gray areas. in this particular case i'd like to live with the question as long as its useful

Comment: Yeah I know, I hesited, but I thought that a developer should already have the same problem as me(and be as disappointed as me when I find only website which don't want to share their content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this, but maybe you can use it for your demo:

http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1

Answer (score 1):

For this specific kind of data, try:

- http://www.themoviedb.org/
- http://www.thetvdb.com/

Comment: Yeah, I saw the first link already, but I still didn't get any response to my API key request, and they say I don't have the right to store them on my disk :/. For the second, I sent him an email, but it seems there isn't a lot of movies there, I don't know if this is enough to show what pivotViewer is capable of.

Comment: @J4N: Well, if it's just a demo, the second should work fine for small values of "movies."  Just hitting up the "specials" of each show will result in a number of movies.  You can also look into the scrapers that XBMC uses.